# How to create portable hybrid WebView library

Tags: android, razor, xamarin, webview

Xamarin has a RazorTodo sample that demonstrates how to build a hybrid app using WebView and razor.  It contains a portable library that contains the views, models, and so forth.  However, when adding a program for the portable library, I can't find a template for that.  I can create a normal "portable" library, but it doesn't have a "Views" folder.  I can create one, but then there's no template for adding .cshtml files.  I can create a file of a different type with the .cshtml extension, but it would be nice for VS to know about the type.  Am I missing something?

Thanks.

-John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Views folder is just convention.  It is perfectly legitimate to just add the folder.

If you are working inside of Xamarin Studio, you can add a .cshtml file to your project by choosing "Preprocessed Razor Template" under "Text Templating" in the "New file" dialog.

Visual Studio doesn't currently include this template type, but you can easily add a Text File or HTML File to your project, named with the .csthml file extension, and turn it into a preprocessed razor template by editing the properties on the file and setting "Custom Tool" to *RazorTemplatePreprocessor*.